# React native Linking.getInitialURL() return null when opening the app from Android gmail

Tags: javascript, android, firebase, react-native, deep-linking

I'm opening up my app's reset password screen from an email that in the Gmail app(Android). If I tick "Open Web links in Gmail" setting in Gmail general settings, the link that I have in the email does not redirect to the correct screen. But if I un-tick above setting it is working fine.

This is in my splash screen

```
  componentDidMount() {
    Linking.addEventListener('url', this.handleUrl);
    Linking.getInitialURL().then((ev) => {
      //ev is null in above case
      if (ev) {
        this.handleUrl(ev);
      }
    }).catch(err => {
        console.warn('An error occurred', err);
    });

  }

  handleUrl = (url) => {
    const eveUrl = this.evaluateUrl(url); 
    Linking.canOpenURL(eveUrl).then((supported) => {
      if(supported) {
        this.addRoutesToDeepLinking(eveUrl); //navigate to correct screen
      }
    })
  }
```

This is totally working fine in iOS with Gmail app and also it is working fine in other email clients like Outlook with Android.
(I'm using firebase dynamic links)

AndroidManfest.xml>

```xml
 <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
            <data android:host="xxx.page.link" android:scheme="https"/>
        </intent-filter>
```

And,

```xml
android:launchMode="singleTask"
```

Comment: Is the configuration in AndoridManifest file correct to handle dynamic link?

Comment: Yes, Like I said it is working fine if I open the link in chrome, I updated the question with manifest config